# More colloquial term for "confidant"

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, single-word-requests

Is there a more colloquial term for a "**confidant**", or someone who has been entrusted with sensitive information to be disclosed only under certain conditions?

This is related to my [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8575/word-to-describe-when-sensitive-information-is-given-to-a-trusted-proxy-in-case) on trusted proxies.

Comment: trusty? trustworthy? discreet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Harry Potter, they call that person a "Secret Keeper", although that also involves magic and whatnot.

In computer terms, a group of people who are entrusted with secret information (such as SSH keys) are indicated to be a part of (or within) a circle of trust.

In High School, girls call those people BFFs.

Comment: Funny, I thought of Secret Keeper right away too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a more colloquial term that fully encompasses the meaning of *confidant*. I can't think of a more formal one, either.

*Confidant* and *confidante* are not particularly formal terms, even if they sound it. These are not uncommon in everyday parlance.

If you truly require something more colloquial, you'll probably have to settle for a longer phrase. Even then, many of the terms I might use to construct such a phrase seem no less formal than *confidant*:

- privileged
- privy
- trusted
- counselor

Comment: +1 one for the point that *confidant* isn’t necessarily terribly formal.

Answer (score 1):

A *right-hand man* is colloquially used to refer to someone whom you can trust with your secrets.

Answer (score 0):

In cryptography, there is concept of "[web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust)" and "[strong set](http://pgp.cs.uu.nl/plot/)".